# RxJS marble testing objects with functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, rxjs-marbles

I am returning from the Observable an object. One of its properties is a function.
After assigning even empty function and emitting the object the `toBeObservable` expectation fails because of non-deep match.

I'm using `rxjs-marbles/jest` for testing. Here's sample test case:

```js
it('...', marbles(m => {
  const source = m.cold('(a|)');
  const expected = m.cold('(b|)', { b: {
    label: 'A',
    action: () => { }
  } });

  const destination = source.pipe(
    map(() => ({
      label: 'A',
      action: () => { }
    }))
  );
  m.expect(destination).toBeObservable(expected);
}));
```

The result is as follows:

```sh
expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

Expected: [{"frame": 0, "notification": {"error": undefined, "hasValue": true, "kind": "N", "value": {"action": [Function action], "label": "A"}}}, {"frame": 0, "notification": {"error": undefined, "hasValue": false, "kind": "C", "value": undefined}}]
Received: serializes to the same string
```

The only thing I need to check is whether the `action` is defined in object. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out one can define `expected` like this:

```js
const expected = m.cold('(b|)', { b: {
    label: 'A',
    action: expect.any(Function)
  } });
```

And the result will match.

Weird thing tho, I think I tried it few days ago and then it wouldn't work, but maybe I did it somehow different.